# Type inference on lambdas

Tags: java-8

I have been converting some code to use Java 8 features. In the following contrived example

```
    Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "cheese", "5").stream().map(line -> {
        try {
            return Optional.of(Integer.parseInt(line));
        } catch (NumberFormatException xep) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }).forEach( v -> 
        System.out.println(v.orElse(999))
    );
```

(the intention is to parse some strings as ints and replace any unparseable values with 999)

The compiler reports

```
error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to CAP#1
System.out.println(v.orElse(999))
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ? extends Object"
```

I've tried casting 999 to an Integer or Object with no success.

It seems that the real problem is that the inferred return type of the first lambda is `Optional<Object>` and not `Optional<Integer>`

If I do this

```
    Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "cheese", "5").stream().map(line -> {
        Optional<Integer> ans;
        try {
            ans = Optional.of(Integer.parseInt(line));
        } catch (NumberFormatException xep) {
            ans = Optional.empty();
        }
        return ans;
    }).forEach( v -> 
        System.out.println(v.orElse(999))
    );
```

it works perfectly, but not quite as elegant. Is there a better way to 'guide' the compiler to the return type that I want?

Comment: Have you tried using `Optional.<Integer>empty()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple fix is to use a target type:

```
return Optional.<Integer> empty();
```

Also I note that you use `Integer.parseInt` which returns an `int`, so you could also use an `OptionalInt` which will solve your problem and save a boxing operation:

```
try {
  return OptionalInt.of(Integer.parseInt(line));
} catch (NumberFormatException xep) {
  return OptionalInt.empty();
}
```

Comment: re : `OptionalInt` - good point, though I was only using 'int' as a simple example. My real problem is I simply can't get my head to remember the parameterised type comes _after_ the dot - I tried `Optional<Integer>.empty()` then gave up on that approach!

Answer (score 3):

As [said by assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26379504/2711488), you can fix it by using `return Optional.<Integer> empty();`.

However, the big question is why are you using `Optional` here at all?

```
Stream.of("1", "2", "3", "cheese", "5").mapToInt(line -> {
    try {
        return Integer.parseInt(line);
    } catch (NumberFormatException xep) {
        return 999;
    }
}).forEach(System.out::println);
```

does the job much simpler when you want to replace the value anyway.

If you want to perform an action for valid values only (the equivalent of `Optional.ifPresent(Consumer))` you may consider the rule that you should prefer pre-checks over catching exceptions when you *expect* invalid values:

```
Stream.of("1", "2", "3", "cheese", "5")
      .filter(Pattern.compile("^[+-]?[0-9]{1,9}$").asPredicate())
      .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

(I simplified the regex; it does not accept all possible `int` values but will reject all invalid)

Comment: The 'int' was just a simple example, my actual code involved looking things up in a complex map-like object. Thanks for `Stream.of()` though, I wasn't aware of that function.

Comment: It’s clear that it’s just a simple example, but the patterns still apply: You don’t need an `Optional` if you use `orElse` within the same stream operation and you may consider pre-checks over catching. Just as some food for thought…

Answer (score 1):

You could do this if you don't want the member variable `ans`:

```
try {
    return Optional.<Integer>of(Integer.parseInt(line));
} catch (NumberFormatException xep) {
    return Optional.<Integer>empty();
}
```

Type inference is complicated and it has limitations, if you really want to know why this happens in this case you'd have to study the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html).

Comment: There is no need for a target type in the try block

Comment: @assylias I just tried it out, you're right. Strange though that it's not necessary there...

Comment: I suppose because `Optional.of(someInteger)` clearly is an `Optional<Integer>`, whereas the compiler can't determine the generic type of `Optional.empty()` without more context.

Answer (score 1):

The @Assilyas [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26379504/1594933) is correct. I would like to propose an alternative based on the guava utility [`Ints::tryParse`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#tryParse(java.lang.String)):

> Unlike [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html?is-external=true#parseInt(java.lang.String)), this method returns null instead of throwing an exception if parsing fails

With it and the new [method references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), you could write:

```
Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "cheese", "5")
        .stream()
        .map(Ints::tryParse)
        .map(Optional::ofNullable)
        .forEach(v -> System.out.println(v.orElse(999)));
```